# Sinon.js: spy empty callback

Tags: javascript, sinon, sinon-chai

i'm trying to test callback functions with sinon.js

```
handleLoginActions = function (callback) {
    ...
    if (callback) {
        callback()
    }
    ..
}

var loginCallbackStub = stub();
handleLoginActions(loginCallbackStub);
expect(loginCallbackStub).to.have.been.calledOnce; //works great
```

But the problem is when i need to test the scenario with invalid callback function, I get this error: **null is not a spy or a call to a spy! (and i'ts logic)**

```
var loginCallbackStub = null;
handleLoginActions(loginCallbackStub);
expect(loginCallbackStub).to.not.have.been.called;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot inspect that which is not a spy!

Comment: Yep i know, it make sense. But, what would be the best way? Or the way haha

Answer (score 0):

Invoking something that is not a function will throw an error, so you should test that it does NOT throw an error:

```
expect(handleLoginActions()).to.not.throw(Error)
```